# Are internet installations possible with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Many distros out there supply a *internet install* option where a small installation ISO is downloaded and is used to prepare the system to download the rest of the necessary packages directly from the internet.

This offers some small advantages compared with the standard CD install present in Ubuntu.

Is there a way to to a internet install with Ubuntu? What would be the reasons against supplying this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equient is the minimal CD

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

The minimal CD downloads the newest packages but is a minimal, command line install. Post install you would then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` , or the desktop of your choice, or you can install only what you want.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems

I suspect it has not been popular enough to list on the downloads page, but I am not sure. You could file a "feature request" on Launchpad to list the minimal CD on the downloads page.