# How to install Xubuntu complete version from the terminal?

Tags: xubuntu

I currently use Ubuntu 11.10 64bits and would like to switch to Xubuntu.

If I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

will it install only the desktop environnement (XFCE, if I'm not mistaking) or will it install everything like from a Xubuntu LiveCD?
Indeed, as I'm new in the GNU/Linux world, I'm trying several distros and so would like to know if it was possible to proceed that way to install other distros...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would install `xubuntu-desktop`

[image: Install via the software center]

xubuntu-desktop is a metapackage

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

Or a list of all the packages contained in the xubuntu-desktop, which is xfce + additional packages / customizations , same as on the xubuntu CD.

For sfce vs xubutnu-desktop see also

[Xubuntu desktop minimal installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96641/xubuntu-desktop-minimal-installation/96660#96660)

You will keep the additional packages included in ubuntu, so you will have more then would be included with the xubuntu cd.