# What do I need to install after minimal Xubuntu installation

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, software-installation, xfce, ubuntu-minimal

I had an old and low-specced pc lying around and since there's no point selling it I decided to install linux on it just for fun :P It's a Toshiba Tecra 8000 (192MB RAM and 380MHz Pentium II) so I had to do a minimal installation. I installed xubuntu (and later realised I also needed xfce4 to have a desktop). My question is what else would I need to have a proper (but efficient) OS. I found some info here

[Xubuntu desktop minimal installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96641/xubuntu-desktop-minimal-installation)

but I'd like to know what file manager and browser you'd recommend for these kind of specs.

Will xubuntu be usable or would lubuntu or another distro be better?

Thanks in advance, keep in mind there's no hurry as this is just a little side project.

Have a nice day! :D

Comment: This sort of question has been asked many times and thus I marked it as a duplicate. You need to use light weight applications as much as possible and there are multiple options. Start with the defaults for xfce (xubuntu) . Keep in mind , with those specifications, you box is going to be slow. You might even be better off with an alternate light weight distro such a tinycore.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that. Is there somewhere I can look through applications and see what I want to install? Otherwise it's kinda hard to know what to install without asking.

Comment: Arch maintains a nice list - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications and then there is tinycore - http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/

Comment: It is not a problem to ask. It is just, to avoid duplication of effort, rather then answer the same question over an over, we consolidate into a single "best answer" and direct you to duplicate questions / answers. You did nothing wrong, just how this site sort of works.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thunar** which is the default file manager of xfce is pretty lightweight. For browsing the web **Midori** provides a minimal solution.