# Install alternative desktop environment without non-free/patent-encumbered packages

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

How can I install an alternative desktop on an existing Ubuntu install **without** installing the restricted extras (or any other non-free or known patent-encumbered packages)?

For example, if I install the `xubuntu-desktop` package, it installs packages like `gstreamer1.0-libav`, which would normally have to be installed from the restricted-extras package instead. I could just install the desktop environment itself (`xfce4` package), but that would leave off all the normal packages that Xubuntu comes with, including desktop themes, etc.

Comment: Related: [Xubuntu desktop minimal installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96641/xubuntu-desktop-minimal-installation) - you could also consider installing `xubuntu-desktop` with the `--no-install-recommends` option

Comment: I have `xubuntu-desktop` installed, there are no packages from the `restricted`-repository installed. Your example `gstreamer1.0-libav` is in the `universe`-repository.

Comment: @mook765 however the `gstreamer1.0-libav` package appears to be pulled in as a dependency of the (recommended) `parole` media player

Comment: @mook765 `universe` doesn't contain copyright/license restricted packages, but it does contain patent-encumbered packages. For example, see the subpackages of `ubuntu-restricted-extras` -- many are `universe`.

Comment: @steeldriver That's helpful, but it's not what I'm trying to do here. I want a full installation (not minimal), just without non-free license or known patent-encumbered packages.

Comment: You really need to edit your question and add that you don't want the non-free or patent-encumbered packages in your desktop at all.  However, this sounds to me like you might have to build your own desktop and not go with one that is prepackaged.

Comment: @Terrance Updated, feel free to change it more if you think necessary. Are you basically saying that only the default flavour would come without those packages by default?

Comment: I just installed Kubuntu from the ISO to test and even without checking the "install non-free" box, it installed MPEG codecs, etc, so I think you may be correct there. Any suggestions on how to "build my own desktop" (@Terrance)?

Comment: Look into starting with the Core of it then build from there:  https://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/

Comment: @Terrance Ah, so that would have to be per desktop then, right? For example KDE would have to have its own minimal installation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know all the distros that have Core installs.  But yes, it is per desktop.  You might also look into the Minimal installs that allow you just to choose the packages that you want.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD  But those are only for clean installs.