# how do i install ubuntu from a copied version of original ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are internet installations possible with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95466/are-internet-installations-possible-with-ubuntu)

I copied ubuntu from its original cd version..

They way i did it was wrong..i copied the original cd to a folder in harddisk and burned it 
using nero to other cd..

And the cd doesnt boots by itself.

And later i converted all into an iso img and wrote it to another cd after i red a blog..

there must be some bootable file missing from the cd i guess..

and i also tried the flash drive installation..nothing makes any difference..

Its been 2 weeks..and im so tired of doing it..

am i hopeless??

without buying an ubuntu disk can i make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You never need to buy an Ubuntu disk. While they are burnt at the right speed with the correct files, you shouldn't need to worry about that. Rather, just head on over to the download page on Ubuntu's site and download an ISO and burn it to a disk...they have guides even for if you need help.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

Comment: im really sorry my internet connection is speed is really poor..so there are no other options?

Comment: I feel your pain about the connection speed. I would say at this rate, there is no other option because if the boot files are missing from the disc image, there are more files missing too. If you can, I would try to find a way to find someone who can download an ISO for you or try to find somewhere to download it if you have a laptop. You may have to purchase a disk at this point, unfortunately. I'm sorry I couldn't be much help

Comment: thank a lot buddy. okay ill try to download the iso from somewhere..and the mean time i should tell you..im a big time noob to ubuntu..and how can i add you to my contact list to clear my doubts if its okay with you..are you there is facebook?

Comment: My email address is on my profile...I'd rather not type it out here, but it's there if you need it. And don't worry, I don't know much about Ubuntu myself. Just the basic things that keep my machine in one piece :) Feel free to email me any time you need, I'm always here to help.